# Custom Extension setting shows as unknown configuration

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I created a custom VSCode extension which needs a configuration setting the user settings file of vscode.

Why does the setting shows as unknown configuration? It works as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at your repo and noted that there is an error in your `package.json` file. The `keybindings` and `configuration` nodes must be *inside* `contributes`, like this (I removed `keybindings` since it is empty):

```
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "extension.postMessage",
            "title": "Microsoft Teams: Post Message"
        },
        {
            "command": "extension.postCurrentFile",
            "title": "Microsoft Teams: Post Current File"
        }
    ],
    "configuration": {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Visual Studio Code Microsoft Teams configuration",
        "properties": {
            "microsoftteams.teamswebhook": {
                "type": "string",
                "default": "",
                "description": "Microsoft Teams Webhook"
            }
        }
    }
},
```

I made a [pull request](https://github.com/stefanstranger/vscode-microsoftteams/pull/2) fixing this issue.